# Last item in for loop executes multiple times in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I'm making a JavaScript/jQuery version of a dice game my buddies and I play. Here's a 3 player version of the game:

http://codepen.io/jwnardini/pen/jmygqd

I'm trying to make a version of the game where the user can select how many players are playing, and have the game function in the same way:

http://codepen.io/jwnardini/pen/ZKLVqW

Every time the "Go" button is pressed, it's supposed to move on to the next person's turn, and I use a modular operator if condition in a for loop to check whose turn it is, so i can perform a specific action on their turn.

```
var turn = 0;

$(".goButton").click(function() {
  turn = turn + 1;
  var playerCount = $('#input-number').val();  

  for (i=1;i <= playerCount;i++){
    if (turn % playerCount == i) {
    $(".player" + i + "dollars").append("Hi!");
    }
  }
});
```

This works great for every player I've created, except the last one (player# playerCount). This is because playerCount % playerCount = 0, and i is never 0, so the last player is always skipped.

I tried to work around this with an else statement for when turn % playerCount = 0 :

```
var turn = 0;

$(".goButton").click(function() {
  turn = turn + 1;
  var playerCount = $('#input-number').val();  

  for (i=1;i <= playerCount;i++){
    if (turn % playerCount == i) {
    $(".player" + i + "dollars").append("Hi!");
    } else if (turn % playerCount == 0) {
    $(".player" + playerCount + "dollars").append("Hi!");
    }
  }
});
```

However, when I reach player# playerCount's turn, I get playerCount times "hi!" appended. For example, for 5 players, this is the output in browser:

```
Player 1
$3Hi!

Player 2
$3Hi!

Player 3
$3Hi!

Player 4
$3Hi!

Player 5
$3Hi!Hi!Hi!Hi!Hi!
```

Is this a classic "off by 1" error on my part? Or is my else statement flawed in some way?

Comment: Why use a loop for this when you're only interested in one value out of the loop? Seems like you're just trying to do this: `$(".player" + (turn % playerCount) + "dollars").append("Hi!");`

Comment: ...Or if you're using 1-based indexes, `$(".player" + ((turn % playerCount) + 1)...`

Comment: note that `i` is in global scope because the `var` key word was omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your loop, when you iterate over `playerCount` and try to get the class name to append to.

Instead of the entire loop, try to do the following:

```
var m = turn % playerCount;
if (m==0) {m = playerCount};
$(".player" + m + "dollars").append("Hi!");
```

Comment: This actually worked out better for me in the long run. Here are my conditions:

    `var m = turn % playerCount;
    if (m==0) {...}
    else if (m==1){...}
    else if (m <= 2 < playerCount) {
      for (i=2;i < playerCount;i++){
         if (turn % playerCount == i) {...}
}`

Answer (score 0):

take out the 4th player condition outside the loop. the problem is when `turn ==playercount`, u dont have to enter the loop because that condiiotn is independant of `i` and will always be true hence hgetting executed  times.

```
for (var i=1;i <= playerCount;i++){
if (turn % playerCount == i) {

  $(".player" + i + "dollars").append("Hi!");
}
}
    if (turn % playerCount == 0) {
   $(".player" + playerCount + "dollars").append("Hi!");
 }
```

here is the code working code snippet :

```js
var turn = 0;
var pot = 0;

  $("form").submit(function(event){
    var i = 0
    var playerCount = $('#input-number').val();
    var dollarCounts = [];
    $(".players").empty();
    for (var i=1; i <= playerCount; i++) {
      var player= "player";
      player = player + i.toString();
      $(".players").append(
        '<div class="player-wrap"><div class="player' + i.toString() + ' clearable">Player '
        + i + 
        '</div>$<span class="' + player + 'dollars clearable"></span><br><br><br></div>');
      dollarCounts[i] = 3;
      $("." + player + "dollars").empty().append(dollarCounts[i]);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });


//TURN
$(".goButton").click(function() {
  
  turn = turn + 1;
  var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var dice3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  $(".turn").empty().append(turn);

  
  //Print "Left", "Right", "Center"
  if (dice1 == 1) {
    $(".d1").empty().append("LEFT");
  }
  if (dice2 == 1) {
    $(".d2").empty().append("LEFT");
  }
  if (dice3 == 1) {
    $(".d3").empty().append("LEFT");
  }
  if (dice1 == 2) {
    $(".d1").empty().append("RIGHT");
  }
  if (dice2 == 2) {
    $(".d2").empty().append("RIGHT");
  }
  if (dice3 == 2) {
    $(".d3").empty().append("RIGHT");
  }
  if (dice1 == 3) {
    $(".d1").empty().append("CENTER");
  }
  if (dice2 == 3) {
    $(".d2").empty().append("CENTER");
  }
  if (dice3 == 3) {
    $(".d3").empty().append("CENTER");
  }
  if (dice1 == 4 || dice1 == 5 || dice1 == 6) {
    $(".d1").empty().append("SAFE");
  }
  if (dice2 == 4 || dice2 == 5 || dice2 == 6) {
    $(".d2").empty().append("SAFE");
  }
  if (dice3 == 4 || dice3 == 5 || dice3 == 6) {
    $(".d3").empty().append("SAFE");
  }
  var playerCount = $('#input-number').val();  
  
  for (var i=1;i < playerCount;i++){
  
    if (turn % playerCount == i) {
    
      $(".player" + i + "dollars").append("Hi!");
    }
  }
  if (turn % i == 0) {
      $(".player" + playerCount + "dollars").append("Hi!");
    }  
});

//RESET
$(".resetButton").click(function() {
  turn = 0;
  pot = 0;
  $(".players").empty();
  var playerCount = 0;
  var dollarCounts = [];
  $(".turn").empty().append(turn);
  $(".pot").empty().append(pot);
  $(".d1").empty();
  $(".d2").empty();
  $(".d3").empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="start-form">
        <label for="input-number">Number of players:</label>
        <input id="input-number" type="number">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Set Player Count</button>
      </form>

<button class="goButton" type="submit">Go</button>
<button class="resetButton" type="submit">Reset</button>
<br><br>
<div class="players"></div>
<h1>Turn count: <span class="turn"></span></h1>
<h2>Rolls: 
  <span class="d1"></span> 
  <span class="d2"></span> 
  <span class="d3"></span>
</h2>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1>POT</h1>
<div class="pot"></div>
```

Comment: This worked great! I will try the other techniques, but this is the simplest solution in the context of what I've written so far. many thanks!